# Is there any way to mass background restrict app battery usage?

Tags: battery, battery-life, background-process

My Pixel 2 has been experiencing severe standby battery drain (last night it went from 95-30 while I slept), and I'm pretty sure it's one of my apps' faults since it doesn't happen when I reboot the phone in Safe Mode. So now I'm trying to restrict most of my apps from using battery in the background, but it's a huge pain going through 50+ app battery usage pages to toggle their "Background Restriction" property. There's a page to disable app battery restrictions in Settings > Battery > Adaptive Battery > Restricted Apps, but there's no way to add apps to that list. Is there a mass app battery management settings page/developer option I'm missing, or maybe an app that provides this functionality?

Comment: Look in background and replace them with ones that do not drain your batter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything else because all you have to do if you want to restrict background battery usage is to toggle the slider on all 50 apps which barely takes a minute. But if you want help for a longer lasting battery you should search for "Battery" on the google play store and you will find a lot of apps to help you.